# Selected language only applied to current component but returns to default when switching to other component

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to implement internationalization into my web app. I'm using i18next with React and translation for each component itself works fine. The language is changed through a dropdown menu in the sidebar, visible in each component. (I'm also using react-bootstrap and redux)

Problem: The language returns to the default/browser language when moving to a different component.

E.g.:
I'm in the home menu and change the language from English to German -> Text is translated to English. When changing to a different component through button click, the language of the new component is back to English. In the new component I can again click the dropdown to change the language to German, but of course that is annoying for users to always change the language manually.

How can I persist the language the user selected throughout components? Do I need to fall back to redux and store the language in the store?

App.tsx

```js
function App() {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector( (state: RootStateOrAny)  => state.user.isAuthenticated)
  

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Sidebar isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
          <Switch>
            <PublicRoute exact path="/login" component={Login} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/storage" component={Storage} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/bom" component={BOM} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/products" component={ProductList} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/shipping" component={ShippingOrders} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Sidebar component

```js
function Sidebar (isAuthenticated : any) {
  const dispatch: Dispatch<any> = useDispatch()
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  let dispatchLogout = () => {
      console.log("logout")
      dispatch(logoutUser())
  }

    return (
      <>
        <Navbar bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark" sticky="top">
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col xl lg md sm xs = {3}>
                <Dropdown>
                <DropdownToggle className="menu-dropdown-toggle" size="lg" variant="primary" id="dropdown-basic">
                  {t("menu")}
                </DropdownToggle>

                <DropdownMenu className="menu-dropdown" style={{backgroundColor:'#ADD8E6'}}>
                  <DropdownItem className="menu-dropdown-item" href="/storage">{t("storage")}</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem className="menu-dropdown-item" href="/products">{t("productList")}</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem className="menu-dropdown-item" href="/bom">{t("bom")}</DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem className="menu-dropdown-item" href="/shipping">{t("shippingOrders")}</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
                </Dropdown>
              </Col>
              <Col xl lg md sm xs = {3}>
                <Button className="home-button" size="lg" variant="primary" href="/">{t("home")}</Button>
              </Col>
              <Col  >
                <Navbar.Brand className="brand" href="url">
                  <img className="brandLogo" alt="company-logo" src={Logo}/>
                </Navbar.Brand>
              </Col>            
            </Row>
          </Container>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav"></Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav className="mr-sm-2">
            <LanguageSwitcher/>
            {isAuthenticated? 
              <Button size="lg" id="log" variant="primary" href="/login" onClick={dispatchLogout}>{t("logout")}</Button> 
              : 
              <Button size="lg" id="log" variant="primary" href="/login">{t("login")}</Button>
            }
            
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  user: state.user,
  UI: state.UI,
 });
 
 //this maps actions to our props in this functional component
 const mapActionsToProps = {
  logoutUser
 };

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Sidebar)
```

Language switcher component within sidebar

```js
export default function LanguageSwitcher() {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = (lng: string) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown className="language-dropdown-container">
      <DropdownToggle className="language-dropdown" title="languages" id="_language-dropdown" variant="primary" >
        {<img className="language-icon" alt="language-icon" src={LanguageIcon}/>}
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu style={{backgroundColor:'#ADD8E6'}}>
        <Dropdown.Item onSelect={() => changeLanguage("jp")}>jp</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onSelect={() => changeLanguage("de")}>de</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onSelect={() => changeLanguage("en")}>en</Dropdown.Item>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
```

i18next config

```js
import translationEn from './en/translation.json';
import translationDe from './de/translation.json';
import translationJp from './jp/translation.json';

export const resources = {
  en: {
    ...translationEn,
  },
  de: {
      ...translationDe,
  },
  jp: {
      ...translationJp
  }
} as const;

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
    debug: true,
    lng: 'en',
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'jp', 'de'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    resources,
    keySeparator: '.',
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false
    },
    react: {
        wait:true,
        }
    },
);

export default i18n;
```

Sample component using translation

```js
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function Home () {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    return (
        <div>{t("homeScreen.description")}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. For testing purposes when I still didn't have a button to change the language within the UI, I wrote the following in the configuration file:
lng: 'en'

Therefore, the language always returned to English when switched to a different component.

=> Don't set lng in the configuration file